# How to add delay to KeyDown event

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm stuck, somehow I need to make a delay between keystrokes.

In short, when the button is in focus, you press the spacebar an event occurs, and after that there should be a pause of 2 seconds.

is there a way to do this?

```
private void Button_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
     Button_Click(sender, e); // for this I need 2sec pause 
}
```

Comment: A delay before what happens? The next KeyDown event is accepted, or an action is triggered, or what else?

Comment: Clemens, I updated question with code

Comment: But this should not happen with a mouse click, only with keyboard?

Comment: For the mouse, I use Storyboard and IsHitTestVisible = false, not the most elegant solution, but it works )

Comment: That sounds terrible. What are you *actually* trying to achieve? Do you just want to avoid that any button action is executed more often than every two seconds?

Comment: Correct, just want to avoid that any button action is executed more often than every two seconds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the Click handler async. Then disable the Button, wait for an appropriate time span, and enable it again. And set the focus if it was focused before.

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Button_Click");

    var button = (Button)sender;
    var isFocused = button.IsFocused;

    button.IsEnabled = false;

    await Task.Delay(2000);

    button.IsEnabled = true;

    if (isFocused)
    {
        button.Focus();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, simple and elegant solution... I was thinking of using IsEnabled, but the problem was the loss of focus. I did not know that it could be returned so easily (facepalm)...

Answer (score -1):

After you press spacebar add in this 2 second timer.. You can see i have a label that will be displayed for 2 seconds. you can put whatever you need here.

```
System.Timers.Timer time = new System.Timers.Timer(2000);
            time.Enabled = false;
            time.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(timeElapsed);
            void timeElapsed (object send, ElapsedEventArgs ev)
            {
                lblTime.Visible = false;
                time.Enabled = false;
            }
            time.Enabled = true;
            lblTime.Visible = true;
```

Comment: If you need a timer, use a DispatcherTimer, anything else is nonsense. Besides that, what you are showing here would be much easier implemented with `await Task.Delay` in an async event handler - instead of a timer. But we don't know if that is what OP wants.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend looking into Rx (Reactive Extension). A simple example would be:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    IDisposable keyDownSubscripton;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        keyDownSubscripton = Observable.FromEventPattern<KeyEventArgs>(this, "KeyDown")
            .Do(e =>
            {
                // Do something on key down event
            })
            .Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2))
            .ObserveOn(System.Reactive.Concurrency.DispatcherScheduler.Current) // OnNext on UI thread
            .Subscribe(e =>
            {
                // Do something after delay
            });
    }
}
```